# Set max width for an element inside a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make the first element inside the row to be responsive, but with max width of 500.
The result is the first element size is always 500.

```html
home: Scaffold(
    body: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
          child: const Text(
              "container container container container container container container container container container container container "),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 600,
          child: Container(color: Colors.green),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, all of them, but the first one to be responsive up to 500

Answer (score 3):

Just notice `flex` value first row Item flex value is `6` which means it will take 60% of available space, and second one has `4` which means second one will take 40% of available space

```
home: Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 6,
        child: Container(

          child: const Text(
              "container container container container container container container container container container container container "),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex : 4,
        child: Container(color: Colors.green),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Container`'s [`constraints`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/constraints.html) apply to the child,

> Additional constraints to apply to the child.

While there is no child in your `Container`, you are having this behavior. Add a child on Container.

You can check more about  [UI constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).

**Update:**

I prefer using [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to handle responsiveness.

```dart
 Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth:
                    constraints.maxWidth >= 500 ? 500 : constraints.maxWidth,
              ),
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    55,
                    (index) => Text("conta sner"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but when putting a Text child with long text, the size will be always 500.

Comment: Check the update answer using `LayoutBuilder` .

Comment: Same result (The green SizedBox not pushing the red Container when I'm making the window smaller)

Comment: `Expanded` will get as much size as possible, but here 1st container taking available space based on its view. You can learn more about [Expanded here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Comment: I switched the expanded to sized box. I am trying to create a max sized container, but i want it to shrink when Im making the window smaller, and the 600 px green sized box to push it.

Comment: I prefer just using `LayoutBuilder` with `SizedBox`, While we know the size, we don't even need `Expanded` just wrap with `SizedBox` with and provide size

Answer (score 0):

```
home: Scaffold(
  body:Container(
width: double.infinity,
child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500), color: Colors.red),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green))
    ],
  ),)
),
```

Comment: The solution is not working for me. updated the question.